# Java - What is actually the fastest way to read in a large formatted file and store this

Tags: java, hashmap, store, large-files

What is the fastest way :

- to read the file, (Buffered Reader ??)
- to fast conversion (ex: string to int)

The fastest way store this (ArrayList, HashMap?)

from a **large** file

**[File:]**

Format: Letter hashcode-int double int int int boolean

```
U 1 234.003 30 40 50 true
T 2 234.003 10 60 40 false
Z 3 17234.003 30 40 50 true
M 4 0.500 30 40 50 true
...
/* 1000000+ lines */
```

**[Reader]**

```
public static DataBase filereader() {

   InputStream S = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)
   Scanner FS = new Scanner(S);

   DataBase DB = new DataBase;

   while (FS.hasNextLine() == true) {

       String A  = FS.next();
       int hash  = FS.nextInt();
       double B  = FS.nextDouble();
       int C     = FS.nextInt();
       int D     = FS.nextInt();
       boolean E = FS.nextBoolean();

       // hash is hashcode for all values A B C D E in DataBase DB

       DB.listA.put(hash,A);
       DB.listB.put(hash,B);
       DB.listC.put(hash,C);
       DB.listD.put(hash,D);
       DB.listE.put(hash,E);

   }
}
```

**[DataBase]**

```
public class DataBase () {

public HashMap<Integer,String>  listA;
public HashMap<Integer,Double>  listB;
public HashMap<Integer,Integer> listC;
public HashMap<Integer,Integer> listD;
public HashMap<Integer,Boolean> listE;

/* ... */

}
```

Comment: Using `BufferedInputStream` is a good start, but I would use the other constructor `BufferedInputStream(InputStream, int)` and use a larger buffer than default. This will increase IO reading speed. A suitable value for the second parameter would be e.g. 64KB (`65536`). BTW: Why saving each value in an own HashMap? If you don't need to access each value individually it would be better to create an class that holds all values so you need only one Map. Note that you will lose entries if there is a collision of the `hash` value.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  It depends what you need to do with the data once you have read it.  (Or to put it another, the literal fastest way to read it would be to map the entire file into memory as a `ByteBuffer`.  But then you have the problem of how to use the ... bytes.)

Comment: But storing huge amounts of data in a `HashMap` is neither fast or memory efficient.

Comment: What are you asking? Did you test this and is it too slow? If not, why are you trying to optimize something that isn't bad in the first place?
"Fast conversion", depends on the format, you could write a parser, but Scanner seems to do what you want, so why bother.
"Fastest to store" - store for what? Every data structure has its pros and cons. Storing it in a plain ArrayList surely is fast, but retrieval will then become a problem.

Comment: I want a fast read in a Database and a fast read out with hashvalues

Comment: You can read millions off lines per second with a BufferedReader with the default buffer size. This is fast enough. Your overheads will come elsewhere.